# xmlbeans.xmlexception. illegal XML character 0x0

Tags: java, parsing, arrays, xmlbeans, xmlexception

I create an xml document in C# by converting a string to bytes via System.Text.UTF8Encoding().  I then send this to my java program for xmlbeans to parse via a TCP connection.  No matter what i try, i am getting this error:
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Illegal XML character: 0x0
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.io.IllegalCharException: Illegal XML character: 0x0

I have attempted to sanitize the the string on the C# side, yet it does not find any instance of 0x0.  I have looped through and output each byte in the byte[] that i receive on the java side, and there is absolutely nothing that has a 0x0.

This is my java side code:

```
    public void parseBytes(byte[] bytes, int length, String source)
{
    System.out.println("***************BmsDrawingGatewayParser - ParseBytes  " + length);        

    String foundData = null;
    try
    {
        foundData = new String(bytes, 0, length, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch (readState)
    {             
    case STATE_NEW_MSG:
        // if contains the 
        if (foundData.contains(startMessageTag))
        {
            if (foundData.contains(endMessageTag))
            {   
                byteStream.write(bytes, 0, length);                   
                parseXml(byteStream.toByteArray());
                if (byteStream.size() > 0)
                {
                    byteStream.reset();
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.STATE_READING_MSG;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find start tag");
            System.out.println(foundData);
        }
        break;

    case STATE_READING_MSG:          
        byteStream.write(bytes, byteStream.size(), length);
        if (foundData.contains(endMessageTag))
        {
            System.out.println("Now going to parse");
            //parseXml(xmlString.toString());
            parseXml(byteStream.toByteArray());
            byteStream.reset();
            readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.STATE_NEW_MSG;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find end tag");
            System.out.println(foundData);
        }
        break;
    }                        
}

    private void parseXml(byte[] xmlData)
    {
        System.out.println(xmlData);

        //EventDocument.Factory.parse
        ByteArrayInputStream sid = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData);     
        try
        {
            EventDocument eventDoc = EventDocument.Factory.parse(sid);
            if (eventDoc.validate())
            {
                System.out.println("Document is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Document is INVALID");
            }
            EventDocument.Event myEvent = eventDoc.getEvent();
            EventDocument.Event.Detail[] myDetailArray = myEvent.getDetailArray();

            //myDetailArray[0].

            //BmsDrawingDocument drawingDoc = myEvent.getDetail();
            System.out.println("MY UID: " + myEvent.getUid());
        }
        catch(Exception xmlException)
        {
            System.out.println(xmlException.toString());
            xmlException.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Does anyone know what i might be doing wrong?  Is there more information that i can provide?

Comment: can u change  String foundData = new String(bytes); to String foundData = new String(bytes, Charset.UTF-8);

Comment: I can, but what difference would that make?  I am only referencing it so i can look for a string?  I am never actually passing foundData to my parseXml function.

Comment: can you write the xml to a file in c# and see if you are having additional character at the start or end of the file. or you can sniff the network bytes to see where the null character is

Comment: I wrote it the data out using system.io.file.writealltext.  I did it once without specifying encoding and once with.  They both matched.  I also wrote out hte bytes using a binaryWriter.  None of these showed a leading or trailing null char. I'll see if i can find wireshark somewhere and look.  I doubt that there is really a null in the data, at least coming from my C# side.

Comment: you can write the received bytes to a file and check too

Comment: I believe i have found my issue.  I was being passed in a byte[], and when i sent it to parseXml, i didn't check the size.  the byte[] was 1024, though there was only 384 bytes of data.  I'm hoping that was the issue.

Comment: Yes that was the issue.  Code has been corrected above.

Comment: If you found the answer to your problem, add it as an answer, then click the green checkmark.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void parseBytes(byte[] bytes, int length, String source)
{               
    String foundData = null;
    try
    {
        foundData = new String(bytes, 0, length, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch (readState)
    {             
    case STATE_NEW_MSG:
        // if contains the 
        if (foundData.contains(startMessageTag))
        {
            if (foundData.contains(endMessageTag))
            {   
                byteStream.write(bytes, 0, length);                   
                parseXml(byteStream.toByteArray());
                if (byteStream.size() > 0)
                {
                    byteStream.reset();
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.STATE_READING_MSG;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find start tag");
            System.out.println(foundData);
        }
        break;

    case STATE_READING_MSG:          
        byteStream.write(bytes, byteStream.size(), length);
        if (foundData.contains(endMessageTag))
        {
            System.out.println("Now going to parse");
            //parseXml(xmlString.toString());
            parseXml(byteStream.toByteArray());
            byteStream.reset();
            readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.STATE_NEW_MSG;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find end tag");
            System.out.println(foundData);
        }
        break;
    }                        
}

    private void parseXml(byte[] xmlData)
    {
        System.out.println(xmlData);

        //EventDocument.Factory.parse
        ByteArrayInputStream sid = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData);     
        try
        {
            EventDocument eventDoc = EventDocument.Factory.parse(sid);
            if (eventDoc.validate())
            {
                System.out.println("Document is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Document is INVALID");
            }
            EventDocument.Event myEvent = eventDoc.getEvent();
            EventDocument.Event.Detail[] myDetailArray = myEvent.getDetailArray();

            //myDetailArray[0].

            //BmsDrawingDocument drawingDoc = myEvent.getDetail();
            System.out.println("MY UID: " + myEvent.getUid());
        }
        catch(Exception xmlException)
        {
            System.out.println(xmlException.toString());
            xmlException.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and found out to be corrupted lib files, so replace the libs with uncorrupted or old copy. It solved my issue.